# spinning wheel in react doesn't stops on a specific position and also dosn't gives the exact value where it stops

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.App {
    background-image: url('./images//bg.webp');
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    object-fit: contain;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-image: url('./images/wheel.webp');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: transform 5s; 
    transform-origin: center;
}

.container div {
    position: absolute;
    transform-origin: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    
}

.container .one {
    left: 37.2%;
    top: 5%;
    background-image: url('./images/star1.webp');
    object-fit: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 24%;
    width: 24%;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.container .two {
    background-image: url('./images/star2.webp');
    /* background-repeat: no-repeat; */
    object-fit: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 24%;
    width: 24%;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
    left: 65%;
    top:-4%;
    /* transform: rotate(50deg); */
}
.container  h1{
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 50;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 15px;
    text-shadow: 0px 4px 0px darkred;  /* Dark red text shadow */

    /* height: auto; */
    /* width: 60%; */
}
.container h1 span {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    position: fixed;
    top: 60%;
    font-weight: 800;
    /* text-shadow: 0px 4px 0px darkred; Dark red text shadow */
}
.container .three {
    background-image: url('./images/star1.webp');
    /* background-repeat: no-repeat; */
    object-fit: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 24%;
    width: 24%;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
    left: 68%;
    top:4%;
}

.container .four {
    background-image: url('./images/star2.webp');
    /* background-repeat: no-repeat; */
    object-fit: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 24%;
    width: 24%;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
    left:40%;
    top:-1%;
}

.container .five {
    background-image: url('./images/star1.webp');
    /* background-repeat: no-repeat; */
    object-fit: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 24%;
    width: 24%;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
    left:10.5%;
    top:-39.7%;
}

.container .six {
    background-image: url('./images/star1.webp');
    /* background-repeat: no-repeat; */
    object-fit: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 24%;
    width: 24%;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
    left:8.5%;
    top:-95.5%;
}

.arrow {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 50;
}

.arrow img {
    position: absolute;
    top: -40px;
    left:   -80px;
}

#spin {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px; 
    display: flex; 
    align-items: center; 
    justify-content: center; 
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 100; 
  }
  
  #spin img {
    width: 100%; 
    height: auto; 
    pointer-events: none; 
  }
  


@media (max-width: 540px) {
    .container {
        width: 350px;
        height: 350px;
    }

    #spin {
        top: 52.5%;
        width: 70px;
        height: 70px;
    }

    .container div {
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    .arrow {
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
    }
}




.birds {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    top: 20%;
}

.birds img {
    width: 20%;
}



.stars {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 50;
}

.stars .bird-1 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 10%;

}
.stars .bird-2 {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 10%;
}

.design {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 50;
}

.design img {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: -23%;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import bird1 from "./images/paret.webp";
import bird2 from "./images/paret2.webp";
import star1 from "./images/star1.webp";
import star2 from "./images/star2.webp";
import arrow from "./images/arrow.webp";
import spin from "./images/btn.png";
import PopUp from './components/PopUp';
import bg from "./images/bg3.webp";
import startSound from './audio/start.mp3';
import winSound from './audio/win.mp3';
import loseSound from "./audio/lose.mp3"
function App() {
  const [clicks, setClicks] = useState(0);
  const [rotation, setRotation] = useState(0);
  const [showPopUp, setShowPopUp] = useState(false);
  const [prices, setPrices] = useState({
    price1: 5,
    price2: 1568,
    price3: 1000,
    price4: 15,
    price5: 105,
    price6: 300,
  });
  const [winPrize, setWinPrize] = useState();

  const startAudioRef = useRef(null);
  const winAudioRef = useRef(null);
  const loseAudioRef = useRef(null)
  useEffect(() => {
    const popUpShown = localStorage.getItem('popUpShown') === 'true';
    const savedClicks = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('clicks'), 10) || 0;
    const savedWinPrize = localStorage.getItem('winPrize');
    setShowPopUp(popUpShown);
    setClicks(savedClicks);
    if (savedWinPrize) {
      setWinPrize(savedWinPrize);
    }
  }, []);

  const handleSpinClick = () => {
  if (clicks > 0) {
    return;
  }
  setClicks(1);
  localStorage.setItem('clicks', '1');

  // Assuming 0 degrees is the top of the wheel and segments are evenly distributed.
  const degreesPerSegment = 360 / 6;
  const offsetToCenterOfSegment = degreesPerSegment / 2;

  // Calculate a random segment to stop on, then adjust to the segment's center
  const chosenSegment = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
  const newRotation = rotation + 360 * 5 + (chosenSegment * degreesPerSegment) + offsetToCenterOfSegment;

  setRotation(newRotation);
  startAudioRef.current.play();

  setTimeout(() => {
    const finalRotation = newRotation % 360;
    console.log(`Final Rotation: ${finalRotation}`);
    const winningSector = Math.floor((finalRotation + degreesPerSegment / 2) % 360 / degreesPerSegment);
    console.log(`Winning Sector: ${winningSector}`);
    const winningPrice = prices[`price${winningSector + 1}`];
    console.log(`Winning Price: ${winningPrice}`);

    localStorage.setItem('winPrize', winningPrice);
    setWinPrize(winningPrice);
    winningPrice === "Empty" ? loseAudioRef.current.play() : winAudioRef.current.play();

    localStorage.setItem('popUpShown', 'true');
    setShowPopUp(true);
  }, 5000);
};

  

  const handleClaimBonus = () => {
    setShowPopUp(true);
    setClicks(1);
    localStorage.setItem('popUpShown', 'true');
    localStorage.setItem('clicks', '1');
    // localStorage.removeItem('winPrize');
    // setWinPrize(undefined);
  };

  const handleCloseBtn = () => {
    setShowPopUp(false);
    setClicks(0);
    localStorage.setItem('popUpShown', 'false');
    localStorage.setItem('clicks', '0');
    localStorage.removeItem('winPrize');
    setWinPrize(undefined);
  }


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div id="spin" onClick={handleSpinClick}>
        <img src={spin} alt="Spin" />
      </div>
      <div className='birds'>
        <img className='bird-1' src={bird1} alt="Bird 1" />
        <img className='bird-2' src={bird2} alt="Bird 2" />
      </div>
      <div className='stars'>
        <img className='bird-1' src={star1} alt="Bird 1" />
        <img className='bird-2' src={star2} alt="Bird 2" />
      </div>
      <div className='design'>
        <img src={bg} width={500} height={500} alt="Background" />
      </div>
      <span className="arrow">
        <img src={arrow} alt="Arrow" />
      </span>
      <div className="container" style={{ transform: `rotate(${rotation}deg)` }}>
        <div className="one">
          <h1>FS <span>{prices.price1}</span></h1>
        </div>
        <div className="two">
          <h1>R$<span>{prices.price2}</span></h1>
        </div>
        <div className="three">
          <h1>R$<span>{prices.price3}</span></h1>
        </div>
        <div className="four">
          <h1>R$<span>{prices.price4}</span></h1>
        </div>
        <div className="five">
          <h1>R$<span>{prices.price5}</span></h1>
        </div>
        <div className="six">
          <h1>R$<span>{prices.price6}</span></h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      {showPopUp && clicks > 0 && (
        <PopUp winPrize={winPrize} onClaimBonus={handleClaimBonus} handleCloseBtn={handleCloseBtn} />
      )}

      <audio ref={startAudioRef} src={startSound} preload="auto"></audio>
      <audio ref={winAudioRef} src={winSound} preload="auto"></audio>
      <audio ref={loseAudioRef} src={loseSound} preload="auto"></audio>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I can't seem to find a question here, and the snippet you've posted doesn't work either.